# pratical challenge: retrieving cookies from this site in .Net

Tags: .net, cookies, httpwebrequest, webclient

I have a pratical question here.
I have to access to a site and get the cookies information to reuse it in subsequent navigation. I don't have any browser control on my side, because everything is supposed to run on a server.
With some site the task is pretty easy, but there are some site that send back cookies in a way I cannot manage to intercept.

On example is [Italian highways site](http://www.autostrade.it/): I can't understand how they sent back cookies and most important, how can I capture those cookies from a .Net application.

I've tried both WebClient object, looking into header, in this way:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
var htmlMainPage = wc.DownloadString(new Uri(AutostradeMainSite));
string cookies = wc.ResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"];
```

but I don't get any result.
Even by looking into header, there's no cookies there.

Then I tried with HttpWebRequest object, but I wasn't able to retrieve the cookies:

```
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(AutostradeMainSite);
wr.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
var cookies = response.Cookies
```

What am I doing wrong?

Analyzing the main page of the site with some developer tools for IE or Chrome, I can see that some cookies are sent to the browser, but I cannot see them neither in the header, nor in the javascript... How can it work?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WebClient` class can't handle cookies out of the box, although it's pretty easy to create a derived version that supports cookies. You can do it with the `HttpWebRequest` class, but you need to set the `CookieContainer` property:

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com") as HttpWebRequest;
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebResponse res = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
CookieCollection cookies = res.Cookies;
```

Comment: I tried even with HttpWebRequest tecnique, as you can see from my post, but without any results. The site didn't send back any cookies, or it does in a way I can't intercept.

Comment: I forgot to say... I even enabled cookies creating a new CookieContainer as you suggested... same result: no cookies detected :(

Comment: Well, it works for me... Did you try with other sites ? For me Google returns 2 cookies

Comment: I agree... with google's site it works pretty well. The problem is with the site point out, that is www.autostrade.it.

Comment: I just checked with Fiddler, it's because the home page itself isn't returning any cookie. It includes a javascript file located at */autostrade/service.do?sid=0*, and it is that request that returns the cookie.

Comment: YES! that was the problem! Thank you very much. I didn't know about Fiddler... if it could solves that kind of problem, I really need it. I'm gonna check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The site may be detecting that you're using an unknown "browser", and assuming you cannot accept cookies, so it doesn't even provide one. The answer would be to craft a custom WebRequest that looks like it comes from IE 8 instead of the .NET WebClient. You should be able to do this by setting a value for the User-Agent key of WebClient.Headers.

Comment: Tried to follow your advice: I adding wr.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)";
but nothing changed...
I tried event with Chrome style user agent, but same result :(